# Is the SETI's `needle-sharp at 982.002 megahertz` signal accessible?

Tags: seti, raw-data

In April-May 2019, the Parkes radio telescope, in Australia, [received](https://seti.org/signal-proxima-centauri) a weird [signal](https://seti.org/did-proxima-centauri-just-call-say-hello-not-really) while surveying Proxima Centauri. Is this signal available, ideally in some digitalized form? Where could I download it?

Answer (score 1):

If those data were available to the public, the [Breakthrough Listen Open Data Archive](http://seti.berkeley.edu/opendata) would most likely have them.
Queries there currently return no 982 MHz data for any sources, and "PROXCEN" data only at 3009 and 3094 MHz from 2017-18.
This [Scientific American article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/alien-hunters-discover-mysterious-signal-from-proxima-centauri/) mentions work in progress by Sheikh et al.; they may have dibs on the 982 MHz data from 2019 until they publish their paper.